# how to show query plan in gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

how to show query plan from sql server 2008 to gridview asp.net

my sql server 2008 code is

```
SELECT TOP 10 SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT)
ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1),
qs.execution_count,
qs.total_logical_reads, qs.last_logical_reads,
qs.total_logical_writes, qs.last_logical_writes,
qs.total_worker_time,
qs.last_worker_time,
qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S,
qs.last_elapsed_time/1000000 last_elapsed_time_in_S,
qs.last_execution_time,
qp.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
ORDER BY qs.total_logical_reads DESC
```

i need to display output in gridview

error this

gridview  query_plan column its not showing data...

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Query Plan" >
    <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lblPlan" Text='<%#Eval("query_plan") %>' runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

where i made error ?

Comment: this `gridview query_plan column its not showing data...` is not an error, this is what you do not get, but not an error message from asp.net

Comment: Simple try that for start `<ItemTemplate><%#Eval("query_plan") %></ItemTemplate>` to see if you get anything

Comment: its not showing anythink....

Comment: The check if your query is return anything, show the rest of the code, on how you have connect it to the sql run

Comment: i am binding gridview from datatable....in datatable it has content...

Comment: the content is .... <ShowPlanXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan" Version="1.1" Build="10.50.1600.1"><BatchSequence><Batch><Statements><StmtSimple StatementText="Set dateformat dmy" StatementId="1" StatementCompId="1" StatementType="SET CMD" /><StmtSimple StatementText=";SELECT  * FROM (select  TOP 5 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Query) as ROW_NUM,* from (select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Query desc) as gridviewcoun........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `query_plan` column is XML.

You need to HTML Encode it..

#### ASP.NET 4 + (note the colon after the #)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Query Plan">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblPlan2" Text='<%#: Eval("query_plan") %>' runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

#### Previous versions

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Query Plan">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblPlan" Text='<%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("query_plan").ToString())%>' runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```